# How do I pass a slug to the URL in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

At this point I just want to call a page based on my table.html template. I'll work on adding all of my table data later. Presently, when I click on my link to a table on the index.html page I get a "TypeError... table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'd_100_id'.

I've tried removing unnecessary code from the table view and template, and I checked in an incognito Chrome browser in case I'm getting the old page each time.

My views.py page

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import D100Generator

def index(request):
    latest_table_list = D100Generator.objects.order_by('-d_100_id')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_table_list': latest_table_list
    }
    return render(request, 'generators/index.html', context)

def table(request, table_slug):
    table = get_object_or_404(D100Generator, pk=table_slug)
    return render(request, 'generators/table.html', {'table': table})
```

My url.py (in case this helps):

```
from . import views
app_name = "generators"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('table/<slug:d_100_id>', views.table, name='table'),
]
```

index.html

```
<br>
<h2>Recent tables added include:</h2>
{% if latest_table_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for table in latest_table_list %}
        <li><a href="/generators/table/{{ table.table_slug }}">{{ table.table_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No tables are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and table.html
`<h1>{{ table.table_name }}</h1>`

I wanted it to call at least the table.html page and display the table_name.

What I got instead was an error message at the top of the page:

````
TypeError at /generators/table/your-elf-spent-25-years-learning

table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'd_100_id'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/generators/table/your-elf-spent-25-years-learning
Django Version:     2.2.6
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'd_100_id'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\tirli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 113
Python Executable:  C:\Users\tirli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.4
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\tirli\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Schoolwork\\2020 Fall\\IT '
 '4750\\Capstone\\capstone',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Doc',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\include',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\libs',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Tools',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Schoolwork\\2020 Fall\\IT '
 '4750\\Capstone\\capstone',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\tirli\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 16 Oct 2019 17:29:47 -0600```

I can post the traceback as well if needed.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path should look like this:
`path('table/<slug:table_slug>', views.table, name='table'),`

```
def table(request, table_slug):
    table = get_object_or_404(D100Generator, pk=table_slug)
    return render(request, 'generators/table.html', {'table': table})
```

Also, in template, you can use `url` template tag to reverse the URL rather than hardcoding it:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'generators:table' table_slug=table.pk %}">{{ table.table_name }}</a></li>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and I ran into a "NoReverseMatch at /generators/" error. "Reverse for 'table' not found. 'table' is not a valid view function or pattern name."
It says that ```{% url 'table' table_slug=table.pk %}``` is the guilty portion on the readout.

Comment: Not sure how your urls.py fully looks like. Maybe you need to also pass the namespace? {% url 'generators:table' table_slug=table.pk %}

Comment: Yes, that is right. It should be `'generators:table'` not `'table'`.